# Flot chart trigger error on animate

Tags: javascript, flot

I am receiving the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: chart.trigger is not a functionplotData @ jquery.flot.animator.js:124

On my flot graph:

```
var options = {
    "xaxis": {
        "mode": "time",
        "timeformat": "%d/%m",
        //"tickSize": [1, "day"]
    },
    "yaxes": [{
            "position": "left",
            //"tickSize": 1,
            "min": min,
            "max": 100
        }, {
            "position": "right",
            "min": 0,
            "max": max
        }
    ],
    "series": {
        "lines": {
            "show": true
        },
        curvedLines: {
            apply: true,
        } 
    },
    "colors": ["#00ff00"],
    "legend": {
        "show": false
    },
    "grid": {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    },
    animator: { start: 100, steps: 99, duration: 2000, direction: "left" }
};
```

**I have tried:**

```
plot = $.plotAnimator("#network-graph",  [{ data : [arr], 
    animator: { start: 100, steps: 99, duration: 1000, direction: "left" } }], options);
```

and

```
plot = $.plotAnimator("#network-graph",  [{ data : arr, 
    animator: { start: 100, steps: 99, duration: 1000, direction: "left" } }], options);
```

**I have now tried**

```
plot = $.plotAnimator($("#network-graph"),  [{ data : arr, animator: { start: 100, steps: 99, duration: 1000, direction: "left" } }], options);
```

but it crashes.

When I try the following, it does not crash or any errors pop up however, the data points do not load.

```
plot = $.plotAnimator($("#network-graph"),  [{ data : [arr], animator: { start: 100, steps: 99, duration: 1000, direction: "left" } }], options);
```

Here is the data

```
[1449619200000,99.38],
[1449622800000,99.23],
[1449626400000,99.39],
[1449630000000,99.4],
[1449633600000,99.39],
[1449637200000,99.4],
[1449640800000,99.41],
[1449644400000,99.4],
[1449648000000,99.31],
[1449651600000,99.12],
[1449655200000,99.06],
[1449658800000,98.93],
[1449662400000,98.94],
[1449666000000,99.05],
[1449669600000,99.11],
[1449673200000,99.16],
[1449676800000,99.3],
[1449680400000,99.4],
[1449684000000,99.43],
[1449687600000,99.43],
[1449691200000,99.43],
[1449694800000,99.43],
[1449698400000,99.43],
[1449702000000,99.44],
[1449705600000,99.46],
[1449709200000,99.37],
[1449712800000,99.41],
[1449716400000,99.38],
[1449720000000,99.36],
[1449723600000,99.34],
[1449727200000,99.37],
[1449730800000,99.36],
[1449734400000,99.3],
[1449738000000,99.16],
[1449741600000,99.03],
[1449745200000,98.93],
[1449748800000,98.97],
[1449752400000,99.01],
[1449756000000,99.03],
[1449759600000,99.11],
[1449763200000,99.2],
[1449766800000,99.26],
[1449770400000,99.31],
[1449774000000,99.34],
[1449777600000,99.34],
[1449781200000,99.33],
[1449784800000,99.32],
[1449788400000,99.37],
[1449792000000,99.33],
[1449795600000,99.32],
[1449799200000,99.31],
[1449802800000,99.34],
[1449806400000,99.34],
[1449810000000,99.33],
[1449813600000,99.33],
[1449817200000,99.33],
[1449820800000,99.21],
[1449824400000,99.05],
[1449828000000,98.82],
[1449831600000,98.85],
[1449835200000,98.94],
[1449838800000,99.04],
[1449842400000,99.11],
[1449846000000,99.17],
[1449849600000,99.25],
[1449853200000,99.25],
[1449856800000,99.32],
[1449860400000,99.4],
[1449864000000,99.37],
[1449867600000,99.09],
[1449871200000,99.06],
[1449874800000,99.19],
[1449878400000,99.42],
[1449882000000,99.43],
[1449885600000,99.43],
[1449889200000,99.41],
[1449892800000,99.41],
[1449896400000,99.4],
[1449900000000,99.4],
[1449903600000,99.43],
[1449907200000,99.41],
[1449910800000,99.31],
[1449914400000,99.26],
[1449918000000,99.2],
[1449921600000,99.21],
[1449925200000,99.27],
[1449928800000,99.35],
[1449932400000,99.39],
[1449936000000,99.43],
[1449939600000,99.45],
[1449943200000,99.47],
[1449946800000,99.48],
[1449950400000,99.47],
[1449954000000,99.46],
[1449957600000,99.51],
[1449961200000,99.51],
[1449964800000,99.52],
[1449968400000,99.52],
[1449972000000,99.5],
[1449975600000,99.47],
[1449979200000,99.48],
[1449982800000,99.48],
[1449986400000,99.5],
[1449990000000,99.5],
[1449993600000,99.44],
[1449997200000,99.36],
[1450000800000,99.36],
[1450004400000,99.37],
[1450008000000,99.37],
[1450011600000,99.39],
[1450015200000,99.43],
[1450018800000,99.48],
[1450022400000,99.52],
[1450026000000,99.51],
[1450029600000,99.52],
[1450033200000,99.52],
[1450036800000,99.52],
[1450040400000,99.51],
[1450044000000,99.5],
[1450047600000,99.49],
[1450051200000,99.5],
[1450054800000,99.5],
[1450058400000,99.5],
[1450062000000,99.49],
[1450065600000,99.49],
[1450069200000,99.5],
[1450072800000,99.48],
[1450076400000,99.5],
[1450080000000,99.5],
[1450083600000,99.38],
[1450087200000,99.2],
[1450090800000,99.11],
[1450094400000,99.08],
[1450098000000,99.1],
[1450101600000,99.12],
[1450105200000,99.23],
[1450108800000,99.37],
[1450112400000,99.41],
[1450116000000,99.42],
[1450119600000,99.43],
[1450123200000,99.42],
[1450126800000,99.43],
[1450130400000,99.44],
[1450134000000,99.43],
[1450137600000,99.4],
```

I am using following code to plot graph, which works.

```
if(DEBUG){      
        g_start = new Date().getTime();
        console.log("start graph render: " + g_start );
    }
    var data_ajax = [{
            "color" : "#A8B400",
            "label" : "R1 Graph",
            "lines" : {
                "show" : true,
                "lineWidth" : 1
            },
            "points" : {
                "show" : false
            },
            "yaxes" : 1,
            "data" : arr,
            animator: { start: 100, steps: 99, duration: 1000, direction: "left" }
        }
    ];
    $('#network-graph').empty();
    //plot = $.plotAnimator($("#network-graph"),  data_ajax, options);
    plot = $.plot("#network-graph",  data_ajax, options);

    bind();
    if(DEBUG){      
        g_end = new Date().getTime();
        console.log("finish graph render: " + g_end );
        console.log("process graph render duration : " +  ((g_end - g_start)/1000) + "s" );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your HTML id string with the jquery selector:

```
plot = $.plotAnimator($("#network-graph"), [{ data : arr, animator: { start: 100, steps: 99, duration: 1000, direction: "left" } }], options);
```

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvwx5hdj/) loads and animates without the error (it has the jQuery selector surrounding the `id` of the `div` in `$.plotAnimate()`).

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvwx5hdj/1/) reproduces the error you're seeing when the animation is finished (it doesn't have the selector in `$.plotAnimate()`).

In both of the above JSFiddles, you can open up the developer tools of the browser you are using and look at the console to see the error (or lack thereof).

Comment: @bonez I updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvwx5hdj/2/) with your new code and it still works. Can you reproduce in a fiddle?

Comment: here is https://jsfiddle.net/shorif2000/cq6chwu8/ If you try run that it crashes.

Comment: fixed the problem time value was string had to parse as int